# Maven Compiler Plugin 3.x:

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven problem right now. I created a new test project to simplify the problem:

The error seams to be:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 59 more
```

-v gives me:

Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /home/ubuntu/workspaces/projectx/test/EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

And the pom is:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
</project>
```

This gives me:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.170s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 06 22:21:53 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/115M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project test: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

using -X adds:

```
    Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /home/username/workspaces/projectX43/test/EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from EMBEDDED/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/username/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/username/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /home/username/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[..... (Limit of 30000 would be exceeded so I left it out) .....]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project test: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project test: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
urls[8] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
urls[10] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
urls[11] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
urls[13] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
urls[8] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
urls[10] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
urls[11] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
urls[13] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
urls[8] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
urls[10] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
urls[11] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
urls[13] = file:/home/username/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:125)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1855)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:629)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:831)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:954)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:950)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.get(AbstractMap.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.DefaultCompilerManager.getCompiler(DefaultCompilerManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 59 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume you having problems downloading dependencies. Best is to try to delete the local repository and retry the build from scratch. Do you have any other warnings/errors in your log output?

Comment: I checked the local repo and the plexus artefact is correctly downloaded. I also used the -U Option and deleted the artefact  . its the same... class not found exception

Comment: The `-U` doesn't matter, cause it's only required for SNAPSHOT's but not for releases. Apart from that can you show the full pom of the project which is causing this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue with the chronos plugin and resolved it by adding the plexus-utils dependency to the plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>chronos-jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.15</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have not had this issue with the compiler plugin, but this might work for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of the "active / current" versions of the maven-compiler-plugin.

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/
Note that today's version of the maven-compiler-plugin is in 3.6.1, this way to change this value.

Change your maven plugin to:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Reason: Every time the maven compile plugin is run, it is reindexed with the Maven central repository, so this version must be continually updated.

Note: Do not include dependency on "plexus", this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have a missing jar file. This can be easily added through maven by added the following dependency (in your pom.xml file before the  tag):

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks. I Was not aware of that plugins do not include their own necessary dependencies.

Comment: The root cause if this is something else, cause the plugins will download all their dependencies automatically without explicit given their dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried added the dependency? What happened? Could be the dependency is being used by something else and not the plugin itself. I am not that familiar with the implementation of the maven compiler plugin

Answer (score 0):

I got this because of low memory on a C drive... cleaned up and that allowed dependencies to be successfully downloaded :)

Comment: :) I had plenty of disk space... .

Comment: Well, that only proves that there can be different reasons for this exception and one of them could be low disk space. Just saying, it may help someone who comes by this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this because of the maven repository file has been locked! And I cant operated this file! But I don't know why? Then I removed the repository file, And --> Maven ReImport. It work! This may be help you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help ...
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException #420](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/issues/420)

```
Delete ~/.m2 local folder completely.
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `./m2/wrapper` helped me.

Comment: `./m2/wrapper` does not appear in the question. Where do you remove it from?