# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError only in particular conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, maven

My problem is that when class B tries to use A.check() my execution stops due to a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

So here is my class configuration. NB: the classes are in the same packages and I have already checked that the A.class file is placed where it should be.

```
public class A{
    // vars 

    // declare some public method

    public synchronized static boolean check(){
           //do stuff, log some info and return boolean
    }
}

public class B implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        A.check();
    }
}
```

And here is my stacktrace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/mypackage/A
>   at org/mypackage.B.run()
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org/mypackage.B
>    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)

The project is really big and class A is used lots of times before this call without any problem, so i don't think that is something relative to the classpath. Note that this is part of the last call of the software that should close up everything.

Moreover, I have two maven goals: the first one execute the questioned code without any problem, instead the second rise this error every time.

Comment: can you post the two different maven goals you mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean? They are two custom goals that I inserted as maven plugin. Do you need the code of those plugins?

Comment: Make sure your classloader is same

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823184/maven-compiler-plugin-3-x

Comment: Are you using a Plexus Compiler plugin? Is the configuration different?

Comment: @tak3shi not that I know. One of the two plugin is the mvn test plugin that run some unit test on a testapp, the other is a custom plugin created in a file.java

Comment: @rakwaht so the error happens only with the custom plugin, I would say this is the key detail then, what is this plugin doing? how is this plugin executing the mentioned code?

Comment: @rakwaht It would be usefull to see, what maven plugins you are using. As you can see in the stacktrace org.codehaus.plexus Classloader is used and cannot find the class.

Comment: @tak3shi, @ A. Di Matteo. The first plugin is a default maven plugin named test that in my case will load a webapp and is doing instrumentation on the fly on each class while the junit test cases call them. After this phase it calls the code in the question to close up everything. The second one is doing exactly the same thing but not based on the tests but is performing the instrumentation in a file .war that contains the same webapp already compiled. So they actually execute the same code (same instrumentation ) and the only difference is how they get the classes(from test or from a .war).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have solved my problem and I post here the solution so maybe can be useful for someone else.

**First of all the error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**
This error is really different from ClassNotFoundException and this is where I'have lost a lot of time.

NoClassDefFoundError in Java is raised when JVM is not able to locate a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time. For example, if we have a method call from a class accessing any member of a Class and that class is not available during runtime then JVM will throw NoClassDefFoundError. It’s important to understand that this is different than ClassNotFoundException which comes while trying to load a class at run-time only and the name was provided during runtime, not on compile time. Many Java developer mingles this two Error and gets confused. Here I [quote](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) a really useful blog that I uesd.

*So in a shorter way NoClassDefFoundError comes if a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime.*

But even with those information the problem was still there until I found the mystery: one of the reason that can place the class in a state that can be compiled but not located at runtime is that if you have static initialization that fail (e.g. in my class I had as field a static variable instantiated badly).

**So remember to check for you initialization phase if you have static variables in your class this could be the reason of your java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.**

By the way I don't get why this kind of error is not raising some more meaninful errors for example java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError or something like that.

Comment: It really saves me a lot of time searching for solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @James you're welcome, just upvote the answer so it can be useful also to other people :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug maven execution by running: `mvn -X <your_goals>`

It would be useful to see your POM file.

Comment: As Yogesh_D rightly pointed at static blocks, this exception is often caused by a failure during class initialisation in those blocks. I would also suggest isolating the problem by taking your POM file and the affected classes into a new project and executing them on their own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with spring mvc and if you made bean entry in dispatche-servlet.xml for Controller class.

Example :

```
<bean id="MyClass" class="com.aaps.myfolder.MyClass">
    <property name="methodNameResolver">
        <ref bean="methodNameResolver" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

And if MyClass.java is not compiled & if no class file is generated in classes folder of your project folder then it wil show java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

So check whether the MyClass.class is created or not in classes folder if you are working with spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Does Class A have anything that is done in a static block. You can get this exception even if a class is being loaded and static blocks fails for any reason reason. try to put in logging to see if something like this is happening.

Comment: As you can see in my sample of code yes my A class has static vars and also static methods

Comment: So either add in logging or debug it to see if it fails with any exceptions.

Comment: @rakwaht Yogesh_D is talking about static blocks, not about vars or methods.

Comment: Was just about to comment what @tak3shi said, static blocks in Class A not static methods. Also note, that if you have some static fields, and the classes that these refer to have any static blocks the same can happen.

Comment: sorry my fault, no there are no static blocks in any of the involved classes.