# "mvn sonar:sonar" build fails while running my custom rule plugin for java

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar scanner is throwing following error while is run for my maven project.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project spring-boot-rest 
example: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing 
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: org/sonar/java/checks/helpers/MethodsHelper
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven plugin:3.4.0.905
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/prakharpandit/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/prakharpandit/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/prakharpandit/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/prakharpandit/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/prakharpandit/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/prakharpandit/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The stacktrace looks similar to the https://stackoverflow.com/q/19823184/4944847

Answer (score 0):

We got the same error with our own sonar plugin after we updated the sonar-java plugin in SonarQube from 5.1.1 to 5.3 because they changed the API.

So you have to update the dependency in your sonar plugin. Then you will get the compile errors there and can fix them.

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/commit/3f5df2ec58cb0ca8580b0d07c5bfeffe7318f1f8